# Transformation of fermionic creation and annihilation operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fermions

How do the creation and annihilation operators of Dirac fermions transform under a Lorentz transformation whose axis is not parallel with the axis of spin quantization?

Comment: What do you mean by "axis is not parallel with the spin quantisation"? In most cases you can always do a standard rotation first and then apply the Lorentz transformation, the complete transformation being the composition of the two.

Comment: I was actually studying Peskin's book and right after equation 3.109 he has mentioned that the axis of spin quantization is parallel to the boost/rotation. To be honest, even I didn't fully understand its meaning. I believe he has made that assumption to simplify the transformation law of the annihilation operator. I wanted to know how that law needs to be modified if that assumption is relaxed.